# Laravel ide-helper installed fine but doesn't generate

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc

BarryVdh's ide-helper has been sucessfully installed to my Laravel project as the composer.json desribes:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
     ...
},
"require-dev": {
    ...
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9"
},
```

Added to providers in app/config as:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
],
```

I assume it partially works as the command **php artisan ide-helper:meta** generates **.phpstorm.meta.php** in the root folder, but the **php artisan ide-helper:generate** command fails with the following simple error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

If I try to generate model info with the command **php artisan ide-helper:models**, asks for overwrite models or to write to _ide_helper_models.php instead, 'no' chosen, it fails and throws the same error above. However, if I add a model to the command (eg. **php artisan ide-helper:models Order** ), after choosing 'no' for overwrite the ide-helper generates  the **_ide_helper_models.php** file without any relevant content, just the default comment block.

What to check in this case?

(phpStorm IDE, win10, Laravel 5.1, Xampp, PHP7)

Comment: Have you tried to check **which** file triggers that error?

Comment: @NicoHaase please post an answer and let me accept it. There was an error you made me to solve.

Comment: Did you get it working on 5.1?

Comment: I don't get that? How should I know about your error???

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake, I didn't check the error log as a lame beginner ;) , and Nico made me to check. Not the error what you  made. :D I want to give the friggin' points to you.

Comment: Note to self: When generating, not just the models included but the helpers too. There was an error in a helper prevented ide-helper to generate.